# Vercel Error Unterminated regexp literal after deployment

Tags: javascript, git, github, next.js, vercel

I've successfully deployed my next js app to vercel and it worked. i even made some changes and still works. but in my last update vercel throws the error `Unterminated regexp literal`. the code works perfectly in my local machine. but it's not re-deploying to vercel.

the path of the error is `,-[/vercel/path0/components/First.jsx:54:1]`

```
...
<div className="flex items-center justify-evenly w-full pt-10 pb-4">
            <a
              href="#sweets"
              className="tracking-wider cursor-pointer bg-[#a18663] w-1/3 px-6 py-2 flex items-center justify-center rounded-md"
            >
              About
            </a>
            <a
              href="#packagings"
              className="tracking-wider cursor-pointer border-[1px] border-[#a18663] text-[#a18663] w-1/3 px-6 py-2 flex items-center justify-center rounded-md "
            >
              Contacts
            </a>
          </div> // this is the line 54
...
```

so why is this error being thrown?